# my character's limbs are stretching instead of rotating

Tags: animation

I'm a beginner on Blender. I have a problem: When I want to animate my character the extremities are stretching instead of rotating like a normal body. For the most courageous, I share my work x) https://workupload.com/file/28bwqwYwMma

if someone can help me to resolve my problem with some pictures to help me... It will be super kind! ^^ thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello Fl4mm3. First thing, make sure that the normals are correctly oriented. Also, as answered in BlenderTribu, Blender is probably struggling with the several layers of mesh of your object, so  you need to separate your several meshes into different objects, parent one object only, transfer the weights to the other objects with the Data Transfer modifier, then join your different objects into one again.

Comment: hello, can you show me with some pictures please? I'm completly lost... I don't even know if that will work... Thanks for your help and I'm sorry for being lost in this ^^'

Comment: You could join us on that discord: https://discord.gg/E6wXbR7A5S

Comment: OK so the problem was that you were not supposed to have several layers of mesh, you've actually applied the Solidify modifier when you should have not ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't apply the *Solidify* modifier, otherwise you'll have several layers of meshes in your object, which will make the parentage fail.